# Kafka Connector : Encountered change event for table table name whose schema isn't known to this connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, aws-msk

We are facing issue with our new connector, we want to capture a change event for mysql table, but we are noticing the error with trace

> `org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:42)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.handleEvent(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:369)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$execute$25(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:860)\n\tat com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.notifyEventListeners(BinaryLogClient.java:1125)\n\tat com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:973)\n\tat com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:599)\n\tat com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:857)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Error processing binlog event\n\t... 7 more\nCaused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Encountered change event for table tablename whose schema isn't known to this connector\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.informAboutUnknownTableIfRequired(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:654)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.handleUpdateTableMetadata(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:633)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$execute$13(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:831)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.handleEvent(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:349`

We are anticipating that after downgrading from mysql version 8.0 to 5.7 we have started facing this issue. We tried deleting the history topic and snapshot mode configs but aren't able to solve it.

The properties are as follows :

```
{
    "name": "speed-account-table-v3",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
        "topic.creation.default.partitions": "1",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "jass config",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "speed-history.speed-account-table-new",
        "bootstrap.servers": "cluster name",
        "database.history.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "tombstones.on.delete": "true",
        "snapshot.new.tables": "parallel",
        "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "2",
        "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval": "true",
        "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-512",
        "database.user": "username",
        "database.server.id": "server id",
        "database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "cluster name",
        "database.server.name": "speed-account-v3",
        "database.port": "portnumber",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "xxxx",
        "database.hostname": "xxxxxx",
        "database.password": "xxxxx",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "name": "speed-account-table-v3",
        "table.include.list": "speed.tbl_account",
        "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-512",
        "snapshot.mode": "initial",
        "database.include.list": "speed"
    }
}
```

We have tried changing our infrastructure by using a different kafka connect as well as completely different MSK, but failed.

Comment: I don't think you need `speed` prefix in table name when you also have `"database.include.list": "speed"`

Comment: @OneCricketeer If you mean in table.include.list, it's supposed to be a fully-qualified table identifier, thus is needed. (Two databases can have table with same name)